# Inferring missing categories based on ranges of other observations in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, mapply

The objective is to create categories (`cat`) for rows without them, based on data with known categories which are used here to build the `data` ranges for `cat` 2 and 4, see table `myrange`.

In my strategy, after generating the category ranges of variation in `myrange` df I use mapply. I am getting the result of `mapply` in columns or rows after transforming into a dataframe. For the sake of appending the result to the original dataframe I created two `if` statements in order to always get the results in columns, I wonder if there is a better way to handle this. After appending the new columns to the original dataframe, a new complete column (without NAs) category is created.

The goal, would be to simplify the function using data.table or dplyr  to avoid the mapply and just append the new columns seen here in `mylogicm` based on the data in `myrange` dataframe and the logic in the `mapply` function.

```
text<-(" cat data
       1  NA 1.50
       5   2 1.08
       6   2 1.10
       7   2 1.30
       9   2 1.40
       10  2 1.41
       11  2 1.45
       12  2 1.50
       13  2 1.56
       14  2 1.56
       20  4 2.55
       21  4 2.71")

mydf1<-read.table(text = text, stringsAsFactors = F)
mydf2<-mydf1[which(mydf1$cat %in% 4==F),]

library(dplyr)

rangefunction<-function(df,colgroup,varcount){
#this creates ranges (cats) based on the observations
  myrange<-as.data.frame(df %>% group_by_(colgroup) %>% 
                           summarise_(MinValue = lazyeval::interp(~min(var), var=as.name(varcount)),
                                      MaxValue = lazyeval::interp(~max(var), var=as.name(varcount))
                           ) )
# Handling of NA categories
  myrangeb<-myrange[complete.cases(myrange),]
  if(nrow(myrangeb)==0){
    myrange[is.na(myrange[,colgroup]),][,colgroup]<-2
  }
  myrange<-myrange[complete.cases(myrange),]
# Assigning 0 as MinValue
    if(nrow(myrange[myrange[,colgroup]==2,])>0){
    myrange[myrange[,colgroup]==2,]$MinValue<-0}
# Checking range overlap
    if(nrow(myrange)>1){
    for (i in 1:(nrow(myrange)-1) ) {#cat
      if(myrange$MaxValue[i]>myrange$MinValue[i+1]){
        print(paste("warning",i,"max > min i+1") )
      }
    }
    }
# this is intended to evaluate the values in the data column of dfs to assign
# them to the ranges created in the previous step. This is useful for data with 
#NA in the cat column (not shown).
  mylogicm<-as.data.frame(mapply(function(x) {x >= myrange$MinValue & x<= myrange$MaxValue}, x=df[,varcount] ) ) 
# transpose to homogenize because
# mylogicm # for mydf1 in several columns while for in mydf2 several rows
  if(nrow(df)==nrow(mylogicm))
  {
    colnames(mylogicm) <- myrange[,colgroup]
  }
  if(nrow(df)==ncol(mylogicm))
  {
    mylogicm<-t(mylogicm)
    colnames(mylogicm) <- myrange[,colgroup]
  }
# transform logical columns to columns with category names in them
  mylogicm<-as.data.frame(mylogicm)
  mylogicm[] <- lapply( mylogicm, factor) 
  col_names <- names(mylogicm)
  mylogicm[col_names] <- lapply(mylogicm[col_names] , factor)
  mylogicm[] <- lapply(mylogicm, function(x) levels(x)[x])
  w <- which(mylogicm == "TRUE", arr.ind = TRUE)
  mylogicm[w] <- names(mylogicm)[w[,"col"]]
  mylogicm <- suppressWarnings(as.data.frame(sapply( mylogicm, as.numeric ) ) )
# merge calculating a mean of categories, when several present
  df$inferredcategory<-lapply(split(mylogicm, seq(nrow(mylogicm))), function(x)  mean(unlist(x), na.rm=T) )
# give a category in a new column only for rows with cat == NA
  df$oldandnew<-df[,colgroup]
  df[which(is.na(df[,colgroup])),]$oldandnew<-df[which(is.na(df[,colgroup])),]$inferredcategory
  return(df)
}

df<-mydf1
df<-mydf2

colgroup<-"cat"
varcount<-"data"

rangefunction(df,colgroup,varcount)
   cat data inferredcategory oldandnew
1   NA 1.50                2         2
5    2 1.08                2         2
6    2 1.10                2         2
7    2 1.30                2         2
9    2 1.40                2         2
10   2 1.41                2         2
11   2 1.45                2         2
12   2 1.50                2         2
13   2 1.56                2         2
14   2 1.56                2         2
20   4 2.55                4         4
21   4 2.71                4         4
```

Comment: What is the expected output for `mylogicm`?

Comment: column(s) to be added to the original dataframes.

Comment: Your code comments are about *what* you're doing with the code but not *why*. Can you explain the intended result?  Like, "if the category's missing and the data is X, then `inferredcategory` should be Y because Z."

Comment: If the category is missing and the data is inside the builded ranges (see myrange), the inferred category should be myrange$cat